# Нужно распарсить данные из логов nginx

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, nginx

PHP, необходимо вытащить из логов данные и записать в бд.

Формат логов:

**127.0.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2019:00:20:06 +0300] "GET /favicon/favicon-32.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1306
"http://modimio.loc/icms/catalog/catalog_edit?id=4" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36"**

**176.59.213.125 - - [22/Mar/2019:06:10:33 +0300] "GET /resize/?pic=..%2Fupload%2Ficms%2Fimages%2Fcatalog%2Fcatalog_1_.jpg&w=200&h=274&tp=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 78134 "https://modimio.ru/store" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14G60 Safari/602.1"**

**83.146.108.57 - - [22/Mar/2019:06:11:28 +0300] "GET /resize/?pic=..%2Fupload%2Ficms%2Fimages%2Fcatalog%2Fpdf_catalog_51.jpg&w=224&h=306&tp=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 100707 "https://modimio.ru/store/nashi_tanki/51-nashi_tanki_9_pt_76b" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"**

Что нужно парсить:

• IP адрес

• Дата/время запроса

• URL

• User-Agent

Внутри User-Agent также нужно распарсить:

• Операционная система

• Архитектура (x86 или x64)

• Браузер

Частично уже что то распарсил:

```
$time = '/(?<time>\b(?=\d+:\d)((?:(?:2[0-3]|[0-1]?[0-9]):(?=\d\d))?(?:[0-5]?[0-9]:)?[0-5][0-9])\b)/';
$date = '/(?<date>\d{2}\/\w{3}\/\d{4})/';
$url = '/(?<url>(?:http:|https:)\/\/.+?(?="))/';
$userAgent = '/"{1,3}(?P<useragent>[^"]*)"$/';
```

Застрял на юзе агенте, помогите вытащить данные, в регулярках совсем юн(
Получилось вытащить целиком строку с юзер агентом но не могу сообразить как ее разбить.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо того, что бы по одной сущности вытягивать со строки, тяните все вместе. Все поля разделены пробельным символом и плюс имеют разные обрамляющие символы.

```
$re = '/(?<ip>[0-9.]+)\s+\-\s+\-\s\[(?<date>[^\]]+)\]\s"(?<request>[^"]+)"\s(?<code>\d+)\s+(?<size>\d+)\s"(?<url>[^"]+)"\s"(?<useragent>[^"]+)"/m';
$str = '127.0.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2019:00:20:06 +0300] "GET /favicon/favicon-32.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1306 "http://modimio.loc/icms/catalog/catalog_edit?id=4" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36"

176.59.213.125 - - [22/Mar/2019:06:10:33 +0300] "GET /resize/?pic=..%2Fupload%2Ficms%2Fimages%2Fcatalog%2Fcatalog_1_.jpg&w=200&h=274&tp=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 78134 "https://modimio.ru/store" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14G60 Safari/602.1"

83.146.108.57 - - [22/Mar/2019:06:11:28 +0300] "GET /resize/?pic=..%2Fupload%2Ficms%2Fimages%2Fcatalog%2Fpdf_catalog_51.jpg&w=224&h=306&tp=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 100707 "https://modimio.ru/store/nashi_tanki/51-nashi_tanki_9_pt_76b" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```